# firebaseAnimatedList empty state

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm using a `firebaseAnimatedList` to load a data set. I'm trying to create empty states for the app to provide the user some guidance when there is nothing to show. I see there is a `defaultChild`, but that is only shown until the query returns. If the query returns empty, the `defaultChild` is removed and an empty page is displayed.

2 potential solutions which both seem inelegant:

1. Run the query before (or simultaneous to) displaying the list and if it returns empty, build empty state instead of the list.
2. Use a `Stack` to show the empty state "behind" the list.

Is there a better way to handle empty states with the `firebaseAnimatedList`?

UPDATE:
Submitted PR to add `emptyStateChild` to `firebaseAnimatedList`: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/256

Comment: I would go for the first option. I don't know of any better way to do that.

The second option is less predictable I believe, unless you know the list would always be "completely full", if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

Create variable outside of Widget method

```
int dataIndex = 0;
```

Inside FirebaseAnimatedList do it

```
      FirebaseAnimatedList(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          defaultChild: const Center(
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          query: _ordersRef,
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
            dataIndex += 1; // Add this line
            var orderId = snapshot.key as String;
            var order = Order.fromMap(
                Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value as Map));
            return OrderTile(order: order);
          }),
      if(dataIndex == 0)
        const EmptyBlock(title: 'Oops!', subtitle: 'No orders found',), // Add Custom Container here
```

And the result is here
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoE5J.png)